# How to add a new column based on another's value

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following SQL query which works great for pulling all of our purchased, and manufactured, parts:

```
WITH purchasedItems AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        'BUY' as MAKE_BUY, PART_NUMBER AS NUMBER

    FROM
        PURCHASES

    WHERE
        ORDER_CREATED_DATE >= (SYSDATE-(365 * 3))
),

madeItems AS
(
        SELECT DISTINCT
            'MAKE' AS MAKE_BUY, FILE_PART_NUMBER AS NUMBER

    FROM
        OPERATIONS

    WHERE
        (FILE_CREATED_DATE >= (SYSDATE-(365*3)))
)

SELECT purchasedItems.*
FROM purchasedItems

UNION

SELECT madeItems.*
FROM madeItems
```

Which works well in producing data like:

```
| MAKE_BUY | NUMBER    |
|----------|-----------|
| Buy      | 1215DE-AA |
| Buy      | 7545IO-EE |
| Buy      | 1214MN-QQ |
| Buy      | 1555XC-DD |
| Make     | 3232EW-UU |
| Make     | 4548GB-II |
| Make     | 7477LA-AA |
| Buy      | 9988NM-OO |
| Buy      | 5624QZ-QQ |
| Make     | 4444BA-BB |
```

However, I am looking for a twist. I need create a new column (like I did for `MAKE_BUY`) to add, essentially, an if statement that says:

```
if program_code LIKE '%SEERS%' THEN 'SEERS' as PROGRAM
ELSE IF program_code LIKE '%HP%' THEN 'HP' as PROGRAM
```

I have tried adding the following to my program:

```
(CASE WHEN (program_code LIKE '%SEERS%') THEN 'SEERS' as PROGRAM)
```

but that dd not work. I get an error ORA-00905: missing keyword.

I would like for it to essentially look like this:

```
| MAKE_BUY | NUMBER    | PROGRAM |
|----------|-----------|---------|
| Buy      | 1215DE-AA | SEERS   |
| Buy      | 7545IO-EE | HP      |
| Buy      | 1214MN-QQ | HP      |
| Buy      | 1555XC-DD | HP      |
| Make     | 3232EW-UU | HP      |
| Make     | 4548GB-II | HP      |
| Make     | 7477LA-AA | HP      |
| Buy      | 9988NM-OO | HP      |
| Buy      | 5624QZ-QQ | SEERS   |
| Make     | 4444BA-BB | HP      |
```

I have not found any resources that allow me to use a case-when statement in creating a new column.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CASE to create new column based on specific text in a string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018423/using-case-to-create-new-column-based-on-specific-text-in-a-string-column)

Comment: You select from purchasedItems twice, and never from madeItems.

Comment: Typo on my part @jarlh, I had to edit proprietary stuff out of the query.

Comment: BTW, you can do `UNION ALL` to gain some performance. (No duplicates will be eliminated anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `case` should look like that:

```
CASE 
  WHEN (program_code LIKE '%SEERS%') THEN 'SEERS' 
  when program_code LIKE '%HP%' THEN '%HP%'
  else '??'
end as PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add the END keyword to the end of your case. Like so:

```
(CASE WHEN (program_code LIKE '%SEERS%') THEN 'SEERS' END as PROGRAM)
```

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: While I don't know anyone who bothers to make that distinction, you are technically correct... I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only 2 conditions then I think this is what you are after:

```
case 
  when program_code like '%SEERS%' then 'SEERS' 
  when program_code like '%HP%' then 'HP'
end as PROGRAM
```

but this means that for any other case this column will be `null`.
In the results you posted I see only the value `'HP'` and no values containing `'HP'` as a substring. 
 If this is the case then you don't need:

```
program_code like '%HP%'
```

just

```
program_code = 'HP'
```

is more efficient.
The same applies to `'SEERS'`. 
So maybe you can simplify to:

```
case when program_code in ('SEERS', 'HP') then program_code end as PROGRAM
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @forpas. the `program_code` field is a big text field, so the `LIKE` is necessary. The end result would be simply `SEERS` or `HP`. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Fine but why do you want the result to be `'%HP%'` and not `'HP'`?

Comment: that is an edit that has been corrected. If you look at the desired results table at the end of the post, you would see I wanted the result to be `HP`. The additional `%` was only a typo in the pseudocode.

Comment: I saw the answer you accepted contains this: `when program_code LIKE '%HP%' THEN '%HP%'`

Comment: Correct, and it was simply edited out. I don't understand the point of your comment; that answer was first, and it was correct, so why not accept it?

Comment: That answer was first right, and correct how? If you use that code you will not get the right results. Anyway, all this is enough to clarify.